# Send object from c++ to qml. What about free memory?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qml

There is a model inherited from QAbstractListModel, I use it in qml. One of the properties of this model are parameters, they are specific to the element type of this model. That is one element the parameters of this class TemperatureParam, DifrentParamType another, a third still something... How can I pass an object to qml and to be sure that the memory is freed after use? The code below now works as I need to, but it seems to me that it's not safe.

Param class is so trivial:

```
class QuickTemperatureParam : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float param1 READ param1 WRITE setParam1)
//...
};
```

Model class (**Here's what I'm asking**):

```
class SectionsModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
//...
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
{
//...
    int type = getType( idx );
    if (type == 1)
    {
        auto p = new QuickTemperatureParam( idx );
        p->deleteLater(); // This is all right or no?
        return qVariantFromValue(p);
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    //...
}
};
```

QML something like this:

```
ListView {
    model: sectionsModel

    delegate: Rectangle {
        color: model.statusColor

        ItemDelegate {
            text: model.title
            highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem

            onPressed:
                switch ( model.type )
                {
                case SectionType.Temperature:
                    temperatureParam.openItem(model)
                    break;
                case SectionType.Lighting:
                    lightingParam.open(model)
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

Popup {
    id: temperatureParam

    function openItem(model)
    {
        var p = model.param

        params.itemAt(0).range.from = params.itemAt(1).range.from = p.min
        params.itemAt(0).range.to = params.itemAt(1).range.to = p.max

        params.itemAt(0).range.setValues( p.dayMin, p.dayMax )
        params.itemAt(1).range.setValues( p.nightMin, p.nightMax )

        open()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership):

> When data is transferred from C++ to QML, the ownership of the data
>   always remains with C++. The exception to this rule is when a QObject
>   is returned from an explicit C++ method call: in this case, the QML
>   engine assumes ownership of the object, unless the ownership of the
>   object has explicitly been set to remain with C++ by invoking
>   QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership() with QQmlEngine::CppOwnership
>   specified.

Generally an application doesn't need to set an object's ownership explicitly. As you can read [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#ObjectOwnership-enum), by default, an object that is created by QML has `JavaScriptOwnership`.

Objects returned from C++ method calls will be set to `JavaScriptOwnership` also but this applies only to explicit invocations of `Q_INVOKABLE` methods or slots.

Because the method `data` is not an explicit C++ method call, you should consider to set the object ownership to `QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership` calling `setObjectOwnership()`

So, in general:

- Don't use `QQmlEngine::CppOwnership` if you want QML to destroy the object. The associated data will be deleted when appropriate (i.e. after the garbage collector has discovered that there are no more live references to the value)
- A `QSharedPointer` probably wouldn't work. You have more information [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Shared_Pointers_and_QML_Ownership).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about it. Thanks for the reply. 
But I tried setObjectOwnership and it works for me much worse than deleteLater. If I leave deleteLater will it be safe enough if QQmlEngine and my model are created in the same thread. After exiting the function temperatureParam.openItem (QML) this object I no longer need. Or the object may be deleted before?

Comment: @lirik90 Thanks to you! Well, I didn't say to remove the `deleteLater` line of code. Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly :( If `data` is executed during `temperatureParam.openItem` (am I right?), then I think `p` won't be deleted unless you set its ownership to `QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership`.

Comment: So, to be safe, would it be reasonable to always set `QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership` when handing off a `new` object to QML, even when the above implies that QML would take ownership? In that case, I'd consider this to make the transfer clearer: `template <typename T> T* TransferObjectOwnershipToJavaScript(std::unique_ptr<T> ptr) { T* result = ptr.get();    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(ptr.release(), QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);    return result; }`.