# QML object from C++ class not being destructed?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've encountered an unexpected behavior (for my point of view) of objects from C++ classes created in QML part of application. An example to be clear:

1. The starting point is empty QML application.
2. After that TestEntity class is added:

```
#ifndef TESTENTITY_H
#define TESTENTITY_H

#include <Qt3DCore>
#include <Qt3DExtras>

class TestEntity : public Qt3DCore::QEntity
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestEntity(QNode *parent = nullptr);
    ~TestEntity();

};

#endif // TESTENTITY_H
```

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "testentity.h"

TestEntity::TestEntity(QNode *parent) : Qt3DCore::QEntity(parent)
{
    Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh *mesh = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh();
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();

    mesh->setXExtent(12);
    mesh->setYExtent(6);
    mesh->setZExtent(6);

    Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial();
    material->setAmbient(QColor(Qt::black));
    material->setSpecular(QColor(Qt::white));
    material->setShininess(4);

    this->addComponent(material);
    this->addComponent(mesh);
    this->addComponent(transform);
}

TestEntity::~TestEntity()
{
    qDebug() << "TestEntity destroyed";
}
```

3. TestEntity is registered in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<TestEntity>("testEntity", 1, 0, "TestEntity");
```

4. main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt3D.Core 2.15
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.15
import Qt3D.Render 2.15
import Qt3D.Extras 2.15
import QtQuick3D.Materials 1.15

import testEntity 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Scene3D {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Entity {
            id: rootEntity

            RenderSettings {
                activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                    camera: camera
                    clearColor: "transparent"
                }
            }

            Entity {
                components: [
                  PointLight {
                      color: "#ffffff"
                      intensity: 0.5
                      enabled: true
                  },
                  Transform {
                      translation: Qt.vector3d(15, 0, 15)
                  }
                ]
            }

            Camera {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 45
                nearPlane : 0.1
                farPlane : 150
                aspectRatio: 1
                position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, -20.0, 20.0)
                upVector: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            }

            TestEntity {
                id: testEntity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected except the destruction of TestEntity object - destructor is not called for some reason...
So the question is what is the proper way to add testEntity in QML, so that it'll be rendered and destroyed without any problems?

Thank in advance!

Comment: You are adding ```TestEntity``` QML component to the parent ```Entity```. It is not being destroyed because it's not intended to be destroyed at all. Try to dynamically load/unload the whole ```Scene3D``` using a Loader or something to see the results.

Comment: it should be destroyed when applicationwindow is destroyed anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send object from c++ to qml. What about free memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491263/send-object-from-c-to-qml-what-about-free-memory)

Comment: @kenash0625 destructor is not being called even with `testEntity.destroy()` in ApplicationWindow `onDestruction`.

Comment: @folibis I'm afraid it does not... But it seems that I've accidentally found the solution. To summarize: 1. Destructor is not called automatically in such an implementation. 2. Destructor is called if testEntity is added to `data` property of Scene3D or other high-level QML object. But then graphics stops rendering, most likely because `testEntity` stops being visual child of `rootEntity`. 3. Destructor is called if `testEntity.destroy()` is called manually from ApplicationWindow `onClosing` (not `onDestruction`(!))